# Event registration email missing: additional attendee info, tax information, total ammount

Tags: wordpress, civievent

Additional detail regarding "tax information" above: To be absolutely clear on this item - the confirmation email contains 4 columns for each "order"

- Item
- Qty
- Each
- Total

There should be additional information here regarding the tax being applied to the total. While the "Total" above does ultimately account for the tax, it leaves no explanation as to why there is a difference between the amounts shown in "Each" and "Total". As this is the only record of their transaction out of the CRM this = not good.

In addition, even though the line items from above are ultimately displaying their totals, the Total at the end of the email is not being calculated and is blank.

Here is an example of the end of a registration email to a test user:

> Event Registration Fee
> Participant 1
> Item   Qty Each    Total
> Registration Level - Tech Mogul
> Whether you are a well...
> 1  $55.00  $60.16
> T-Shirt Size (Venture Capitalist & Tech Mogul Only) - Women's Medium (M)   1   $0.00   >$0.00
> 1/4 Zip Pullover (Women's) - M 1   $38.00  $41.56
> Participant 2
> Item   Qty Each    Total
> Registration Level - Startup (free)
> Newbie or veteran,...
> 1  $0.00   $0.00
> T-Shirt Size (Venture Capitalist & Tech Mogul Only) - Free Startup Level (no shirt >w/package) 1   $0.00   $0.00
> Participant 3
> Item   Qty Each    Total
> Registration Level - Startup (free)
> Newbie or veteran,...
> 1  $0.00   $0.00
> T-Shirt Size (Venture Capitalist & Tech Mogul Only) - Free Startup Level (no shirt >w/package) 1   $0.00   $0.00
> Total Amount
> Registration Date  December 20th, 2022 11:33 AM
> Transaction Date   December 20th, 2022 11:34 AM
> Transaction #  
> Paid By    Credit Card
> Event Attendee
> First Name
> Last Name
> Email Address
> Custom User Name
> Street Address
> City (Primary)
> State (Primary)
> Zip/Postal Code
> Country (Primary)

While I did not see anyone posting the issue here (other than a mildly similar post regarding the payment page), I did find the following Issue in Github from 4 years ago:
https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/224

It looks like the exact problem we are having but I am not certain of it. Hoping that it was just an issue with the older version of CiviCRM we had, we upgraded to the latest release, and the issue persists.

Has anyone else run into this issue and found a workaround?

Comment: What is your Tax Display Setting (under Admin - CiviContribute - CiviContribute Component Settings)?

Comment: @LarsSG - Enable Tax and Invoicing = checked. Automatically email invoice when user purchases online = UNchecked. Tax Term = "Sales Tax". Tax Display Settings = "Show [tax term] exclusive price - i.e. $ 120.00 + $ 20.00 [tax term]". As a side note, this only breaks in this way when the user registers multiple attendees. Single user registration works as intended .

Comment: And just to confirm, you're using the default template (if you go to Admin - Communications - Message Templates - System Workflow Messages and look for the Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line) template, it has an Edit link beside it, not a Revert link as well)?